# Conditional manipulation of NAs in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, bigdata, na

I have a data frame containing observations for various individuals.

The first column contains the name of the individual, and the following columns contain the observed states, whereas each column represents one month.

During the observation period, individuals are born, resulting in `NA` observations before their birth, and they leave the population for a reason displayed in the last observation, resulting in `NA`s following the last observation. I would like to change the `NA`s before the first observation to a certain value, and change the `NA`s following the leaving of the population, to the last observation.

Since the data frame comprises more than 30,000 rows and about 400 columns, I am looking for an efficient way, other than a basic `ifelse()` approach.

Comment: Can you post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`na.locf()` in the `zoo` package replaces NAs by carrying the last non-NA value forward. (Not only for *trailing* NAs, but also NAs in the middle of a vector - I assume you don't have those.) By default, it omits leading NAs. You can replace those by a specified value like this:

```
> library(zoo)
> xx <- c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA)
> replacement.for.initial.NAs <- -1
> foo <- min(which(!is.na(xx)))
> c(rep(replacement.for.initial.NAs,foo-1),na.locf(xx))
[1] -1 -1  1  1  2  3  3  3
```

You can loop this over your individuals. There is probably a smarter way involving `apply()` and friends to do this process per row or column of your data structure.

Comment: Great, I will give it a try, and get back to you. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that `na.locf` has an `na.rm=` argument and zoo's `na.fill` can be used to fill NAs with a specified fill value: `na.fill(na.locf(xx, na.rm = FALSE), -1)`.  Also works if `xx` is a matrix.